# Aggregation in MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

How can we find tha maximum and minimum element of a column in a .csv.

What should we pass into context.write(key,value) of mapper.

1. Whether it is each column of that csv file?

[**Solution**](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/calculating-min-and-max-of-columns-in.html)

Comment: You wouldn't. You would do that in the reducer.

Comment: Brian Roach thank you for the reply: so what does mapper do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit broad for an SO question but I'll bite.

Your mapper is for mapping values to keys. Lets say your CSV has 4 columns with numeric values:

> 42, 71, 45, 22

You map a key to each value; effectively what would be like the header in the CSV. Lets say column 4 represented "Number of widgets". You'd map "number_of_widgets" as the key to the value of column 4 in your mapper.

The reducer is going to get all the values for a given key. *That's* where you figure out your min/max. You just iterate though all the values for the key and keep track of the min and max.

Comment: That would cost an extreme amount of data to be transferred and sorted. I would just emit min/max of a column for each task and then min/max the remaining values in the reducer.

Comment: How would you emit the min/max of the input - a row - to get the min/max of the column at the end?  Where are you keeping the column-wise optima?

Comment: @jtravaglini the mapper can determine the column min and max of its subset and emit them with keys columnname_min and columnname_max.

Comment: It's *possible* to pre-aggregate in the mapper but it's not exactly straightforward. Without a custom record reader you don't know when you're reached the end of the input split (e.g. there's no more records for the mapper). You'd have to put logic in `cleanup()` to emit the min/max (in the new API; in the old API it's even uglier)

Comment: How to get the headers seperate from the csv file

Comment: @ThomasJungblut:I done a map which finds each column value and store in hashmap then in cleanup i found the min/max value and again in reducer i emittedmin/max. But for a 14MB file I am getting a Error: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: @UnmeshaSreeVeni no idea how many columns you have, but storing 2 values per column shouldn't take too much memory.

Answer (score 1):

Mapper should transpose the file - for each line read, emit the key as the column number and the value as the value of the column.

Reducer should min/max.  For each input key, emit the min and max value found.